# Does $fd(M)\lt \infty$ and $id(M)\lt \infty $ imply that $R$ is Gorenstein?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

$(R,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring. $M$ is a nonzero finite $R$-module of finite *injective dimension($id$)*. It is known that if $R$ is Gorenstein, then $M$ has finite *flat dimension ($fd$)*. I wonder if the converse is true?  So the question is:

> Does $fd(M)\lt \infty$ and $id(M)\lt \infty $ imply that $R$ is Gorenstein? ($M$ is a non-zero finite $R$-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  As you have stated it, this is a theorem of H.-B. Foxby (Math. Scand. 40 (1977), 5-19, "Isomorphisms between complexes with applications to the homological theory of modules." http://www.mscand.dk/article/download/11671/9687)  Actually, Foxby says "projective dimension" instead of "flat dimension", but for finite modules over Noetherian local rings these invariants coincide.

Comment: In fact, this theorem already appears in the first tome of the *Séminaire Samuel Algèbre Commutative* (1966/1967)

Comment: That's surprising.  On what page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even with no finiteness assumption on $M$. See Bourbaki, *Algèbre Commutative* X, §8, exercise 8 c).

Comment: what do you mean by " X, §8, exercise 8 c"? it is till VII

Comment: version:  Elements of Mathematics 
Commutative 
Algebra   Originally published as 
ELEMENTS DE MATHEMATIQUE, ALGEBRE COMMUTATIVE 
© 1964, 1965, 1968, 1969 by Hermann, Paris

Comment: Unfortunately they are not translated, but chapter 8 to 10 exist in french and are published by Springer.